# Complicated non-linear inequality reduces to simple linear equality. How?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers, proof-writing, factoring

I'm solving a complex inequality, and I obtain the expression $$8xy+x^2y+2\ge3x^3+5x^2+3xy^2+4x-y^3+y^2$$ and I get stuck. This is somehow equivalent to $y\ge3x-1$ which means that I got it correct however I'm unable to show that the expression I obtain reduces to the simple linear inequality. My guess is that there is probably a neat factorisation of the terms leading to cancelation but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right:
$$8xy+x^2y+2-(3x^3+5x^2+3xy^2+4x-y^3+y^2)=$$
$$=(y+1-3x)((x+1)^2+(y-1)^2)\geq0.$$

We can rewrite our inequality in the following form:
$$y^3-(3x+1)y^2+(x^2+8x)y-3x^3-5x^2-4x+2\geq0.$$
Now, easy to see that $\frac{1}{3}$ is a root of $3x^3+5x^2+4x-2,$ which gives:
$$3x^3+5x^2+4x-2=3x^3-x^2+6x^2-2x+6x-2=(3x-1)(x^2+2x+2).$$
Id est, we need to prove that
$$y^3-(3x+1)y^2+(x^2+8x)y-(3x-1)(x^2+2x+2)\geq0.$$
Now, we can check a factor $y-3x+1$.

Indeed, $$y^3-(3x+1)y^2+(x^2+8x)y-(3x-1)(x^2+2x+2)=$$
$$=y^3-(3x+1)y^2+6xy-2y+(x^2+2x+2)y-(3x-1)(x^2+2x+2)=$$
$$=y^3-(3x-1)y^2-2y^2+6xy-2y+(x^2+2x+2)y-(3x-1)(x^2+2x+2)=$$
$$=(y-(3x-1))(y^2-2y+x^2+2x+2)=(y-3x+1)((x+1)^2+(y-1)^2)\geq0.$$

Comment: Curious to know how you deduced step $2$ from the first equation.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Me too, I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: @The Demonix _ Hermit We know that $y+1-3x$ is a factor. In evening I'll show a full solution. I just very busy now. Sorry.

Comment: It is easy this way , but proving the other way round would be much harder.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg That sure is the way I posed the problem knowing the solution in advance, however the original problem statement doesn't provide that knowledge at all so it would be nice to know of any way we could reason without relying on the solution in advance?

Comment: @ahra I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you let $y=3x-1+z$, then $z$ might emerge as a factor, leaving a quadratic that you might be able to show is positive.